# IE 8 input type text/password bug

Tags: internet-explorer, input, rendering, passwords

```
<tr>
 <td>Password:</td>
  <td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password"/></td>
</tr>
```

The code above increases the CSS offset of the input element 6 pixels right.  If the type is changed to 'text' as opposed to 'password' the CSS offset is not increased.

I would file this as a bug with MS but I don't have the time nor energy to jump through their hoops.  In addition it's common knowledge that IE is a sub-standard browser.  We strongly encourage all of our users to abandon IE in favor of a standards-compliant browser.

Comment: Thanks for responding Chris.  Yes, I work-around would be great.

Comment: I'm not aware of a rule that says "`<input>` elements of types 'text' and 'password' must be rendered the same".  Making this not even a standards issue, but a style one.

Answer (score 2):

Form elements have different margins/paddings etc. on different browsers, even if you're using some sort of stylings reset on the root (*such as `<body>`*). This isn't an IE issue, IE just likes to make it more prominent than others.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but have you tried a **Browser Reset CSS stylesheet**?
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

It may remove the additional styles on the password input

Answer (score 1):

If this "bug" only occurs on IE, use a style sheet within a conditional comment so only IE will parse and use it.  But be aware, it's just a happy accident that "text" and "password" input fields both render the same in other browsers.  (It's easier to do so on most OSes, including Windows, but it's not required that they look identical.)

Comment: cHao, I appreciate your input, however the postulation that FF, Chrome and Opera aligning text and password elements consistently, is a "happy accident" and IE's 6px adjustment is par for the course is... well downright absurd.  I agree that it is an issue of style, and MS can classify the issue however they like.  As a forced user of IE, I classify the issue as, at the very least, an oversight.  I will inform my client-base, when asked, that this is a "bug" in IE and should they like the page to appear correctly, they should use a different browser.

Comment: @Martin: I didn't say what was "par for the course".  I'm saying *there's no such thing* as "par for the course" -- you're making assumptions that simply aren't required to be true, and then blaming it on MS when the assumptions don't hold.  I'm not a big MS fan, but this isn't a standards issue -- "standards compliant" doesn't necessarily mean "renders things how i think it ought to".